# default class path java

Tags: java, classpath

my program is in C:\Users\Programs\x.java

X.java is using some files that are in y.jar, z.jar.

y.jar and z.jar are in C:\Users\Programs folder.

(1)
C:Users\Programs> javac x.java

(2)
C:Users\Programs> javac -classpath y.jar:z.jar x.java

I am not getting any errors when I do (2) but when I do (1) I am getting errors. Isn't that classpath is set to current folder. If so why is it not seeing y.jar and z.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath includes the current folder.
However, it does not include subfolders of the current folder.

If you try to use `com.example.MyClass`, Java will look for a file named `com/example/MyClass.class` **directly** inside of each folder in the classpath.
It does not look in subfolders or JARs inside of folders in the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

Contents of a jar residing on the classpath are not automatically added to the classpath itself. A proper classpath in your case would be what you specified in case (2).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, classpath should indeed be set to the current folder by default. However, setting it to a given folder is not the same as setting it to a specific JAR file.